# bad interpreter: No such file or directory in perl script (for beginner in perl scripting)

Tags: perl

We created 1 perl script which will run from one remote server and access the server and will get the data by running the top command for particular process. However whenever i try to run the script i am getting below error.

`./script_GS.pl
-bash: ./script_GS.pl: /usr/local/share/perl^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Script we created as below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use lib "/usr/CSV-2/lib";
use lib "/usr/share/lib";
use lib "/usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/auto/"; 
use lib "/usr/share/man/man3/";
use lib "/usr/local/share/man/man3/";

my $username = 'root';
my $password = 'xxxxxxxx';
my $ip = '1.1.1.1';
my $TERM ;
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new("$username:$password\@$ip", timeout => 30);
$ssh->system("echo $TERM");
$ssh->system("export TERM=xterm");
my ($CPU,$stderr) = $ssh->capture("top -b | head -n 8 | grep -w gis | awk '{    
print \$6}' ");

print "CPU:".$CPU." ";
```

Can seniors please help.

Error which i am getting is

```
 ./Script_GS.pl
 Can't locate object method "new" via package "Net::OpenSSH" (perhaps you   
 forgot to load "Net::OpenSSH"?) at ./Script_GS.pl line 12.
```

Comment: You got an answer to your question. If you have a new question, please ask it in a new question. (Or just search for the answer).

Answer (score 3):

You have Windows line endings, but you're running the script on a Unix system.

To fix this, you can use `dos2unix script_GS.pl`, or if that isn't available, `vi script_GS.pl`, then in the editor, type `:set ff=unix`, then hit ENTER, then `:wq` and then ENTER again.

Comment: i did the same thing and i am getting below error now.

-bash: ./Script_GS.pl: /usr/local/share/perl: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: @LiveCom: What is the output of `/usr/local/share/perl -v`?

Comment: @Stevieb i think i got it what you were saying.. I corrected that but now its giving me different error i updated above in script mode

Comment: You have to install `Net::SSH`, then put `use Net::SSH` at the top of your script. You should also put `use strict;` and `use warnings;` as well.

Comment: Also, you should have asked a new question, instead of asking a new one in an existing thread.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you are not importing NET::SSH but using it. Its like using JDBC conn in java without importing java.sql.* package.

Something like **use Net::OpenSSH;** at the top of the script should fix this error but if you are really so novice, be prepared to get errors like can't locate in @INC or something like these. So you might need to get basic perl lessons first before going to use NET::OpenSSH which is advanced perl package.

Comment: "Obviously" the condescension is high here.

Answer (score 0):

You have transferred the file from Windows to Unix/Linux without changing the newlines. (ascii-mode in ftp)

There are lots of tools and ways to do that afterwards.

In vi:

```
:%s/^M//g
```

To enter ^M: type

> Ctrl-V + ENTER

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your perl script isn't detecting the Net::OpenSSH module. Reinstalling this module should help. Also include "use Net::OpenSSH;" above the importing library code.